# Cannot use toFixed method in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to learn Javascript and create some simple scripts, I was trying to create a Shipping Cost script for me. to calculate the shipping cost of the items that arrive. Everything works fine except the number formatting. I'm trying to format the number with `toFixed()` method. But it doesn't work. and I checked the console the result was

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function (index):23
calculate (index):23
onclick
```

Here is my index.php file :

```
    <html>
<head>
    <title>Shipping cost</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        Price  : <input type="number" name="price" id="price" />
        Pounds : <input type="number" name="pounds" id="pounds" />
        <input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="calculate()" />
    </div>


    <script type="text/javascript">


        function calculate(){

        var price   = document.getElementById('price').value;
        var pounds  = document.getElementById('pounds').value;
        var rule    = parseFloat(price) * 0.04 + parseFloat(pounds) * 7;
        var total   = price + rule;
        var result  = total.toFixed(2); 
        document.write(result);


        }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't use `document.write`, see the warning in [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#document.write%28%29). Use DOM methods instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`price` is a string, so `price + rule` is also a string. And strings don't have `toFixed` method.

If you want numbers, you can use [unary operator `+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_%28.2B%29).

```
var price = +document.getElementById('price').value,
    pounds = +document.getElementById('pounds').value,
    rule = price * 0.04 + pounds * 7,
    total = price + rule,
    result = total.toFixed(2);
```